# PHP Image Saving not working

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, html5-canvas

I recently came across a tutorial from CodeCourse on youtube about saving a canvas/drawing as an image onto a web server. I have followed the tutorial and everything is working fine except for the saving part. I have a web server being hosted on Ubuntu 14.04 on Apache 2. I did a little debugging myself and I am getting two errors-I think they're connected.

All of the HTML is proper and there's no errors regarding that. The error is in the save.js file.  Here is the code:

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveImage);

function saveImage(){
    var data = canvas.toDataURL();

    // save image
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            var response = request.responseText;
            window.open(response, '_blank', 'location=0, menubar=0');
        }else{
            console.log("Failure");
        }
    }

    request.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send('img='+data);
}
```

The first thing I noticed while debugging is that line 16 is running. In the tutorial, he said status 200 is "OK" unlike 404, 500, etc. The second error is on line 22. In the console, I see:

[image: Net Console]

I'm somewhat confused. To me, it seems like there is no php server setup at all but I'm not sure. The tutorial was from 2013, so is this an outdated method?

Comment: The 500 error from the server would indicate you might have a parse error in that PHP script.  Try turning on error reporting or checking the server's error logs.  Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script after the `<?php` tag.

Comment: ^that script being `save.php`, not `save.js`

Comment: In the dev tools in your browser, if you go to the Network tab, and click over the offending link (you can filter it selecting XHR), in the right side it will show up another tab with Headers, Preview and Response. Click in *Response* and you'll see what errors PHP is throwing, if you have `error_reporting` enabled.

Comment: First I tried adding ini_set... and error_reporting(E_ALL);. After doing that, everything was the same except now there's a 3rd failure. (2Failure now says 3Failure). Next I tried checking the Network tab, and see the following: Directly before saving: https://gyazo.com/be982543470453705fa443f7abcea23d                            after clicking save: https://gyazo.com/fa9248e7386ce835694f65a17e4889ed

Comment: Edit: So I've started from scratch on the .js file, and I think I found the problem. I removed the request.status == 200, and just made it 'if(request.readyState == 4)' and a console.log . The log returns true, so the ready state is 4. However the second I do && request.status == 200, it stops returning true. Any idea why the status isn't 200 or what it means? @drew010

Comment: What do you see when you navigate to save.php directly in the browser?  Or don't just look at the status of the response but look at the content as well and see if there was any output.

Comment: When I navigate directly to /save.php on the web browser, it's just a blank page. I redid the entire save.js and save.php files, and I'm still getting a 500 Internal Server Error. Also, I'm using console.log to show whether or not the status of the web page is 200 (OK) and it never is. I'm not sure why I'm receiving this, as I've redone the entire file(s) twice and made sure there are zero problems. Under network I'm still seeing the error in save.php, initiator: save.js:line22,  status 500. Every other file I have shows a 200 status except the save.php. Any idea why? @drew010

Comment: Edit: It appears that at first, the request.status is 200. However at line 22 (request.send('img='+data);) It becomes a 500? That's the line where the error is occuring. I'm not sure what's wrong, or if I need to configure something properly to use that. But that's exactly the code that was shown on the video.

Comment: There's probably a parse error or you're missing some PHP module used by the code.  The server error logs should definitely say something.  And if you put `echo "test";` at the beginning of the script and visit the page and don't see that then there's a PHP or server issue preventing it from running.  The PHP source is more relevant than the JS at this point.

Comment: I put `echo "test";` at the top of the php, directly underneath <?php and there's nothing on the page. So what does this mean? Where exactly would I find an error log or any module(s) I need in order for it to work? Thanks :) @drew010

Comment: If you don't see the echo then there's a PHP fatal error.  Did you also add the error reporting and display errors line at the top of the script?  The location of the server error logs will vary, especially for shared hosting providers but they may be available from your site control panel or management interface.

Comment: I added the two lines to the top of the php file, but what will these do? The network and console tabs still look the same. Also, I have a dedicated machine running Ubuntu 14.04 on Apache 2.4.7 But what will those two lines do? @drew010                                                                                            Edit: I found one location @ /var/log/apache2/ with roughly 20 error.log and access.log.#'s.

Comment: Those 2 lines will make it such that any errors generated by PHP will be output to the client.  So now if you access save.php directly you should hopefully see some errors telling you what's wrong.  and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is probably what you're looking for